# Good internal wiki software

Tags: wiki

I am looking to deploy an internal wiki at work and im looking for a wiki that has a easy to use interface and WYSIWYG editor (For the people who cant find the start menu in vista :) )

Both free and paid are welcome

Comment: Do you have any more specific requirements?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[MindTouch](http://developer.mindtouch.com/) (previously known as Dekiwiki) is pretty nice.  We use it for our Intranet and our users seem to love it.

Comment: I strongly recommend Mindtouch Dekiwiki.  Neat extensibility features, as well.

Comment: I as well strongly recommend Mindtouch. We have been using it for almost 2 years, and have had great success.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at [WikiMatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/), where you can compare them all by [answering a few questions](http://www.wikimatrix.org/wizard.php).

Answer (score 8):

We use the open source [Screw Turn wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/). It is just about to have a new release (version 3) which will support both WISIWIG editing and markup.

It runs in on a windows platform under ASP.net in IIS.

Comment: We use ScrewTurn in our company. Great software for Windows Servers +1

Comment: It needs a better name to be taken seriously.  I use it to provide tech notes to other developers as well as support notes for my project's help desk.

I've heard that Share Point doesn't do well as a public-facing system.  ScrewTurn works well in this area.

Comment: ScrewTurn is awesome.  (ASP based) +1

Comment: Er, ASP.NET to be correct...

Answer (score 5):

We successfully use Mediawiki internally and there's a way of replacing the normal editor with FCKEditor for WYSIWYG editing at [http://mediawiki.fckeditor.net](http://mediawiki.fckeditor.net/).

Not to mention a range of other extensions which may be useful.

Comment: The obvious benefit here is that, if you are deploying to a tech-savvy crowd with possible Wikipedia experience, they will face nearly no learning curve in transitioning to an internal MediaWiki installation.

Comment: Agreed.  Very simple setup, very popular - so there's a ton of resources around if you do get stuck, or need additional features.

Comment: Mediawiki is also awesome.  I give you Wikipedia...

Comment: I've got to be honest, I can't stand Mediawiki outside of Wikipedia.  It has too many design decisions that were made very much with Wikipedia/Encyclopedia in mind, making it a pain to deal with for general purpose use.  I've been at two companies where someone started with a Mediawiki install and then replaced it with something else within six months.  Both times, everyone was much happier with the replacement.

Answer (score 4):

We have been using [Atlassian's Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/), for about two years now.  It has been great, they have other tools that integrate with it.  It does cost money, but it isn't that much and they even have a hosted option so that you don't need to deal with administration.  Confluence also has a built in WYSIWYG editor and has import/export to Word documents and export to PDFs.

One of the big benefits is  that there is a right 3rd party ecosystem for it and many new plugins and features are available.

Comment: On the flip side, it's got kind of weird/awkward markup and a lot of quirks. The ease of adding plugins is a two-edged sword: handy, but it can make upgrades painful. And if you don't have a controlled userbase, plugins can be a security concern. Atlassian Jira is a decent issue tracker, but unless you have a specific need, I personally wouldn't recommend Confluence.

Answer (score 4):

Windows SharePoint Services has a wiki feature with an easy to use interface and a WYSIWYG editor.  It's provided as a free download for Windows Server.

Comment: We use the SharePoint Wiki as well. Assuming you can spare the server and the configuration time, it is good enough for internal use, and has good connectivity to the rest of SharePoint services, and good search built in.
Too bad it supports best only IE.

Comment: We use SharePoint extensively, but personally I hate the SharePoint wiki technology.  I'm hopeful that the next release of SharePoint will improve it....

Comment: At work, some of the upper management is pushing strongly to abandon our internal Wiki in favor of SharePoint.  I have to be honest, I've come to seriously dislike SharePoint.  The SharePoint wiki is an absolute joke compared to a real Wiki Engine, and sharepoint is a huge pain in the ass to work with.

Answer (score 4):

I used Dokuwiki after doing some research using the wiki comparison site: wikimatrix.org.

What I liked about Dokuwiki is that it did not require a database and was easy to setup, administer and extend through PHP plugins. I have found that the plugins are very powerful and that it was pretty straightforward to create new ones (I am not a PHP expert at all) - se my blog post on this: blog.monnet-usa.com/?p=33

I am running Dokiwiki on IIS and used a AD integration plugin to allow Windows Authentication for my users.

Comment: We use Dokuwiki internally and as a backend for a couple low priority sites. We've been middlingly happy with it. It's not a particularly outstanding system once you delve deep into the internals, but it works just fine for the simple use cases. One of the features that drew us to it initially was the user access control, which works fine.

Answer (score 3):

i'm quite happy user of [dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki). in my case it's authenticating users against Active Directory via LDAP.

i can see there is WYSIWYG plugin, but i've never used it.

Comment: We've managed to convince our users to figure out the Dokuwiki syntax, which has been something of a miracle. Works reasonably well for them now though.

Answer (score 2):

[Foswiki](http://foswiki.org/) has a WYSIWYG editor,  see it in action in the highlight video on the home page.

Answer (score 1):

We have successfully used Open Wiki : http://www.openwiki.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/) is the easiest to install that I've used, but it is very limited (formatting and file handling).

I've been using [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) for project management, SVN repository browsing, and issue tracking, and its wiki is very nice. Of course, it isn't just a wiki, so it may be confusing to have the other features if you aren't using them. Trac is my current favorite.

I've used [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/) in the past. The set up was tougher, but the wiki capabilities are excellent. It is the software that drives Wikipedia. It is tougher to set up than Fitnesse and Trac, though.

I've never administered a [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) installation, but I've used the wiki and it is great, but not free. If installation and administration is anything like Atlassian's other products, it will be a breeze. Or you can use it hosted by Atlassian and avoid installation entirely.

There are so many options with so many different features, your best bet is to follow stukelly's advice and check out the [WikiMatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/).

Comment: I found Mediawiki to be a breeze to set up in comparison to Trac. Once I moved to Ubuntu both became easy - apt-get install trac/mediawiki.

Answer (score 1):

One good wiki solution we're using is [XWiki](http://www.xwiki.org/). I recommend it for the following reasons:

- speed, both perceived ( client ) and actual ( server );
- scriptability - you can customise your pages using Velocity, Groovy, Python and ( not sure ) Ruby;
- good WYSYWIG editor;
- active development;
- good turnaround time on reported defects.

Answer (score 0):

We have one we use internally at work which I believe is based on [Tikiwiki](http://www.tikiwiki.org).  There are literally hundreds out there and most are free.  Tikiwiki and Mediawiki seem like good choices.

Tikiwiki is very well supported and has very recent releases.

Answer (score 0):

We use Community Server, which has a decent wiki.  Unfortunately it's only in the Professional edition or above, and Telligent has recently gone off the deep end as far as licensing costs, IMO.

We've also used mindtouch's Dekiwiki, which is pretty solid.

Answer (score 0):

We use Twiki (http://twiki.org/) at Motorola and it works pretty well

Comment: Note, I wouldn't do a new deployment of Twiki right now.  Due to the founder of the project attempting to completely takeover the community developed project, pretty much the entire development community has abandoned Twiki in favor of a fork, Foswiki (http://foswiki.org/).  I'd strongly recommend choosing that over Twiki for new deployments.

Comment: I wouldn't go there. We had an installation of twiki that began ok, but things began to deteriorate afterward. Also, there is no easy configuration, and the WYSIWYG editor corrupts text now and then - especially tables.

Answer (score 0):

From my answer to [#10023](https://serverfault.com/questions/3970):

At my workplace, I dropped ScrewTurn Wiki on one of our Windows dev servers and hooked it up to our SQL Server. It works really well, runs quickly, and mainly stays out of our way for documentation. In the two weeks since it's been deployed, we've already added about 60 pages of information, and it's only for our team (~10 people).

So far, we keep information about current and past projects on there, and have started adding information about the applications such as how to build them from scratch, URL's, and other important information for dev's new to the team.

One of my favorite pages on the wiki has been the tools and libraries page. There, we've started adding information about our favorite productivity tools and libraries that we use a lot, an example of which is grepWin for text searching in Windows.

I would fully recommend checking out the full gamut of wiki's available and find one that suits your intended usage, functionality, and deployment environment. I chose ScrewTurn because it's easy to use, and we had a ton of free room on our local WinServer, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hosted solution that has a great interface and a very easy to use wysiwyg editor. The name of the service is [pbworks](http://pbworks.com)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at a comparison page AFTER you've had a sit down and thought about exactly what you need. Do you need to backup the wiki, and how does it fit in with your existing infrastructure.

A comparison of wikis is on this wikipedia. Look at the "Comparison_of_wiki_software".

Answer (score 0):

I'll put my bias right out front - I work for Microsoft and am the program manager responsible for the next version of SharePoint wikis.

I think that for customers who have a SharePoint environment set up already, the wiki in SharePoint 2007 is a reasonable alternative.

A blog post by one our MVPs describing SharePoint wikis:
http://woodywindy.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!773832677F575173!653.entry

We're not quite ready to share what we're up to next release, but be sure to keep your eyes out for announcements about SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

We're currently using Alfresco as an Open Source replacement for Sharepoint. Our userbase is non technical and they're using it without any complaints or problems.
You can download a pre-configured Vmware VM from Enspeed if you want to give it a try. It supports uploading information trough SMB and Webdav also and Active Directory integration.

Links: