# Good Wiki for SMB with Customer Interaction

Tags: wiki

Hey, I know there's a bunch of wiki questions already but I was wondering if anyone could recommend a good wiki thats good for use internally and can be access by some clients?

Must be free (F/OSS preferred), Ubuntu (9.10+) compatible, and have per-page permissions.

I setup MediaWiki and its fine for internal use but I don't know how, without some severe hackery, how to restrict a client to just view one page and all the images on it and css. It'll be worse when they ask to be able to modify it as well.

Edit: also, please no java solutions

Comment: We had a discussion about this on The SysAdmin Network :
http://www.sysadmin-network.com/forum/topics/wikis-in-the-workplace

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/10662/good-internal-wiki-software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like [moinmoin](http://moinmo.in/) for company uses the reason that it has proper ACL support built into the core.  It works well for the Apache Foundation, Ubuntu, and CentOS so I'm assuming it scales ok even though it's not tied to a database.

It also offers some wysiwyg editing...although a few years ago when I tried that out I had mixed success with complex pages with it.  Like large tables etc.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/10662/good-internal-wiki-software/10667#10667) I like [Mindtouch Deki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MindTouch_Deki) (aka dekiwiki).  Permissions can be applied per page.  The editor interface is easy to use.  It is open source, but there is also a commercial version that has additional features.  Installing is supported on Ubuntu 9.10 the repo is here. (http://repo.mindtouch.com/xUbuntu_9.10/)