# Flexwiki Install Instructions

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, installation, wiki

In another [Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/3970/how-are-you-documenting-your-work-processes-and-environment)  many users recommend FlexWiki for Network Documentation.  [FlexWiki.com](http://www.flexwiki.com)  appears to be down.  I was able to download the latest package from sourceforge.net, but cannot find installation instructions.

Config:  Win2k3 w/ IIS 6.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There is this commercial hosting reference for Flexwiki http://www.seekdotnet.com/flexwikihosting.aspx

Comment: You can usually lookup freshly lost pages through the google cache. I got some data that way which i am posting as an answer since its lot of chars...

Comment: The site is still down.  I like this software but I'm hesitant to install it if this project is toast.  Anyone have any idea what happened to it? Did it move somewhere else?  I tried to find it on CodePlex but only found WikiPlex instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the 'cached' link of a google search with "Flexwiki QuickSetup". Google says this was cached on 27th March 2009.

> PS: This is one more place with some references: [Flexwiki at Winart.com.br](http://www.winart.com.br/flexwiki.web/default.aspx/MyWiki.FlexWiki).

what follows is a cut-and-paste from the google cached page. Sorry for the formatting mess.

---

What you need first

```
* Windows Server 2003 (or XP)
      o Running IIS
* The web-full-Release.zip from the sourceforge download page
```

Steps.

Deployment

```
* If this server is for the FlexWiki, do the following:
      o Unzip the files into the webroot folder (c:\Inetpub\wwwroot by default)
* If you run more web applications (more wikis maybe)
      o Unzip the files into a chosen folder
      o In IIS manager, share this folder as a virtual directory ( more info )
```

later on we will refer to the shared folder as fwfolder.

Giving rights

```
* If you want Anonymous read/write
      o Make sure the IUSR_{computername} user can read fwfolder and can write the subfolders of fwfolder\WikiBases
* Advanced
      o Take a look at fwfolder\Web.config file security settings section (about line 105-147)
```

Now, you are ready to use your flexwiki with a default namespace, try it! (Always use the same domainname in the url, or the cache will mess up links. Eg. don't use http://localhost/flexwiki , just http://myserver.com/flexwiki ).

Configuring a namespace

```
* Open the fwfolder\WikiBases\NamespaceMap.xml and edit the "DefaultNamespace" and the provider parameters
* rename the fwfolder\WikiBases subfolders respectively
* edit the _ContentBaseDefinition through the wiki engine, or at file level
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to alternatives, i have used [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and found it quite easy to setup on windows (even desktop systems).

It includes Apache, MySQL and PHP. MySQL is now owned by Sun Microsystem so you might want to check licensing details.

Comment: MySQL is now owned by Oracle Corporation, if you really want to be paranoid about its future ;)

Comment: Gee, I never noticed that slip! I wanted to write Oracle and managed to write Sun once more for MySQL.